# Proving $x^2 - y^2 + z^2 \gt (x - y + z)^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Prove that

> $$x^2 - y^2 + z^2 > (x - y + z)^2$$

where: $x < y <z$  for all natural numbers.

Thank for help.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the formula $A^2 − B^2 = (A− B)(A+ B)$, will be perfect.

$x^2 − y^2 > (x − y + z)^2 − z^2$

$(x − y)(x + y) > (x − y + z − z)(x − y + z + z)$,

$(x − y)(x + y) > (x − y)(x − y + 2z)$.

Comment: this answer is not complete.  I think the other two is better.

Answer (score 2):

$$(x-y+z)^2-(x^2-y^2+z^2)=2y^2-2xy+2zx-2yz=2y(y-x)-2z(y-x)$$

$$=-2(y-x)(z-y)<0$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:**

$(x-y+z)^2-z^2=(x-y)(x-y+2z) > (x-y)(x-y+2y)=(x-y)(x+y)\\=x^2-y^2$

Comment: you have to reverse the > in the middle since $x-y$ is negative